# Why can't you override parent variable with constant value in child class? (PHP)

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have a class first where `$name` is set to 'bob'. In the child class, I set `$name` to 'Karen' but it doesn't work.

In my echo statements, the 1st one says "bob" instead of 'Karen'. The second one, using a child class method, works though.

Why is this behavior?

```
class First {

    public $name;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->name = 'bob';
    }
}

class Third extends First {

    public $name = 'Karen';
    public function set_name ($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$instance_of_third = new Third;
$third_name = $instance_of_third->name;

echo "<br />We're looking for Karen: $third_name<br />";
// $third_name here is 'bob' from parent class

$instance_of_third->set_name("Karen");
$third_name = $instance_of_third->name;
// $third_name here is 'Karen' only after using set_name()
echo "<br />We're looking for Karen: $third_name<br />";
```

EDIT: I added 2 lines showing what the output was exactly.

Even though `$name` is explicitly set to 'Karen' in child class, it shows as 'bob' unless the `set_name()` function is used to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `Third` does not have it's own constructor, it will inherit the constructor from `First`. Inheritance creates an behaves-as relationship between supertype and subtype.

So when you create a new instance of `Third`, the instance will have a `$name` property of 'Karen', but then the inherited constructor will get called. And that sets the name to Bob. If you don't want that behavior in the subtype, you have to add an empty constructor to `Third`, e.g.

```
class Third extends First
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // prevents parent First::__construct
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/p5VeO2)

An alternative would be to remove the ctor (or at least not set `$name` in it) and preset the `$name` property in the parent to Bob. Then your initial idea would work, e.g.

```
class First
{
    public $name = 'Bob';
}

class Third extends First
{
    public $name = 'Karen';
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xm3LgN)

Please check the chapters on Inheritance and Visibility in the PHP Manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: What's strange about it is I would expect that if someone wanted to extend a class and change one of the properties they could just do it explicitly like I did instead of having to write a bunch of constructor code.

Comment: @ButtleButkus see my update. You can do that. You just have to understand that the sequence of initializing a new instance is: `new Foo` -> creates new instance of `Foo` with default properties -> then automatically invokes `__construct` on that instance to do additional initialization.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a object of class, then constructor is called.

So constructor of parent class is over writing the value of $name in your case.

Comment: $name is set in the child class. Your answer seems to say that the constructor is called first, but that's not what's happening. It looks like the $name gets set first then gets overwritten by constructor... ?

Comment: No, variable is initialized first, then constructor is called

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the constructor is called after fields are initialized , so it overrides your $name field.

Comment: That does seem to be what is happening, but isn't this weird? If you explicitly set the value in a child class don't you assume that's the value you'll get? Or do you use a child class constructor to change it?

Comment: You'll get that value if you don't change it in a method , like constructors. Simply say your code does: 1) create an object with name = 'Karen'; 2) `new` calls the constructor and change it to 'Bob'; 3) the object is assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor overrides the default value. (Generally because it's called after the default value instantiation), a more robust way would be something like so:

```
class First {
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Then call it by:

```
$first_instance = new First("Bob");
```

It will also extend to the `Third` class.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter most likely reads from top to bottom, just like us.

In the first example, you set the public variable to Karen, however since the child class inherits the constructor of the first class, "Bob" will be set.

Comment: Hmm, reading from top to bottom I would think you would instantiate the child class with its inherited value of 'bob', then find it set to 'Karen' in the child class and overwrite 'bob'.

Comment: Yes, but when the class is instantiated, the constructor is called, setting it to Bob. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the $name as static. and access it via Third::$name for example.

```
class First {

    public static $name;

    public function __construct() {

        self::$name = 'bob';
    }

    // edit late static binding
    public function getName() {
       return static::$name;
    }


}

class Third extends First {

    public static $name = 'karen';

}

$instance_of_third = new Third();
//$third_name = $instance_of_third::$name;
$third_name = $instance_of_third->getName();    

echo "<br />We're looking for Karen: $third_name<br />";
```

Comment: that doesnt solve the OP's problem. Or rather, it does, but it no longer addresses the problem at the core. OP has trouble understanding how inheritance works in PHP.

Comment: So, static variables can be overridden by simple assignment. Your code works, but it's strange that Dreamweaver highlights an error at "$third_name = $instance_of_third::$name;"

Comment: i have edited the example. you could also declare a function called getName() in the parent class. The getName returns the name associated with the class. This works in php 5.3 and is called late static binding. As an example : $first = new First(); $first->getName() would return Bob etc.